# Texto innerHTML em tabela aparece e some na hora

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo meio que um cadastro com o localStorage, e utilizando um contador para colocar com o nome, diferenciando assim um dou outro. E depois em um loop para mostrar o resultado em uma tabela com o innerHTML, ai esta o problema, aparece e na mesma hora some.

Codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>HTML5 - Estrutura Básica</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cadastro.css" />
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset id="usuario">
        <legend>Cadastro</legend>
        <p><label for="cCodigo">Código:</label> <input type="text"  id="cod" name="Codigo"  size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder=" Código"/> </p>
        <p><label for="cNome">Nome:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="Nome"  size="35" maxlength="35" placeholder=" Nome Completo" /></p>
        <p><label for="cIdade">Idade:</label> <input type="text" id="age" name="Idade"  size="5" maxlength="5" placeholder=" Idade" /></p>


    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" onClick="salvar()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Mostrar" onClick="mostrar()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Total" onClick="total()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Limpar" onClick="limpar()" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>


    <table border="1" id="tabela">
    <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Idade</th>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Codigo JavaScript:

```
function salvar(){
            var cod = document.getElementById("cod").value;
            localStorage.setItem("nome" + cod, document.getElementById("name").value);
            localStorage.setItem("idade" + cod, document.getElementById("age").value);
            alert("Dados Atualizados");

        }

        function mostrar(){
            var i = 1
            while (i < (localStorage.length/2)+1){
            document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + "NOME : " + localStorage.getItem("nome" + i)+ "</td>" + "<td>" + "IDADE :" + localStorage.getItem("idade" + i) + "</td>" + "</tr>" 
                i++;

            }

        }


        function total(){
            alert(localStorage.length/2);

        }


        function limpar(){
            i = 0;
            cod = 0;
            localStorage.clear();
            alert("Dados apagados!")
        }
```

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço :DD

Answer (score 1):

Na sua função `mostrar`, adicione no fim dela `return false`.

Ao adicionar o `return false` vc faz com que o metodo pare sua execução da sua função e faz também com que a página no seu caso não de um reload.

Comment: Confere onde vão parar respostas tão curtas: http://i.stack.imgur.com/q06bz.png. A ação a tomar é "Parece OK", mas enfim, fica a dica.

Comment: blza. minha intenção é ajudar e não escrever um livro sem necessidade :)

Comment: Certamente, todo mundo respondendo aqui tá oferecendo ajuda grátis e o tamanho da ajuda não é um problema "per se". Uma explicação, ainda que breve, de porquê seu código resolve o problema é a diferença entre "ok" e "ah, entendi!" :)

Comment: Eu coloquei o return false depois de fechar o loop, como vc disse no final da função e continua a mesma coisa :(